# Getting Visual Editor working with WordPress wp editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wp editor` to output a WYSIWIG editor in a custom field. I am using the following function:

```
/**
 * Output native WordPress WYSIWIG editor
 *
 * media_buttons and quicktags are set to true by default
 *
 * @param $helper_text
 * @param $id
 * @param bool $media_buttons
 * @param bool $quicktags
 * @return mixed
 */
function native_wysiwig_editor($helper_text, $id, $media_buttons = true, $quicktags = true) {
    $content= get_post_meta( get_the_id(), $id, true );
    $settings = ['media_buttons' => $media_buttons,'quicktags' => $quicktags ];
    if( strlen( stripslashes($content)) == 0) $content = $helper_text;
    $editor_id = $id;
    $wywisig = wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );

    return $wywisig;
}
```

and I reference it like such:

```
native_wysiwig_editor('helper text here', '_intro_product_test', false);
```

I am confused looking [at the doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) on how to reference the `wp_editor` how to actually get it to show the normal "Visual Editor" instance that plays nice to the frontend user. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you passing 5 arguments to a function that accepts 4?

Comment: yeah sorry. i'm fixing that now